# setState method is not invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My setState method is not invoked, while printing the value after setState always print the default value. I am using expo

import React from 'react';

import KeyboardShift from './KeyboardShift';
import FloatingLabel from 'react-native-floating-labels';

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      focusDescriptionInput: false
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <KeyboardShift>
          { () => (
            <View>
              <FloatingLabel 
              labelStyle={styles.labelInput}
              inputStyle={styles.input}
              style={styles.formInput}
              returnKeyType={"next"}
              onSubmitEditing={() => {
                console.log(this.state.focusDescriptionInput)
                context.setState({
                  focusDescriptionInput:true
                })
                console.log(this.state.focusDescriptionInput)
              }}>
                Email
            </FloatingLabel>
            <FloatingLabel
              labelStyle={styles.labelInput}
              inputStyle={styles.input}
              style={styles.formInput}
              focus={this.state.focusDescriptionInput}>
                Email 2
            </FloatingLabel>


            </View>
          )}

          </KeyboardShift>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems:"center",
    marginTop: 50
  },
  textInput: {
    fontSize: 16,
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 16
  },
  labelInput: {
    color: '#673AB7',
  },
  formInput: {    
    borderBottomWidth: 1.5, 
    marginStart: 20,
    marginEnd:20,
    borderColor: '#333',       
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 0
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried with focus method also to focus next TextInput, but it didn't work.

Comment: where did you get the "context" from? it should be this.setState.

Comment: I have also tried with this.setState({ /* My code */}) but it didn't work.

Comment: How did you know it did not work? Because of this line "console.log(this.state.focusDescriptionInput)" after setState?

Comment: yes, and moreover I am using this.state.focusDescriptionInput in my next FloatingLabel. But also not got updated

Comment: please read my answer, and try to replace "context" with "this"

Comment: Yea. It worked, have commented on that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of **context.setState**, use **this.setState**.

And in your code if you want to print the value of the state after setState, it should be:

```
            onSubmitEditing={() => {
                console.log(this.state.focusDescriptionInput)
                this.setState({
                  focusDescriptionInput:true
                }, () => {
                   console.log(this.state.focusDescriptionInput)
                })

              }}>
```

Why? remember, **setState** is **async**. So, in this example I just used the callback function of setState. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea. this work, Now i am getting correct value for console.log(this.state.focusDescriptionInput), but still my view is not getting updated. As in the very next tag I am using the value of this.state.focusDescriptionInput

Comment: Maybe the issue is not on the state, but on the "FloatingLabel" component.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to make TextInput label floating and on done click it focus on next TextInput. For Floating label I have used this https://github.com/mayank-patel/react-native-floating-labels#readme

Comment: I have also used focus() to focus on next Text Input, but got error as focus() is not a function

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to focus. You don't need to change the state value. You can focus on reference values.

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to save the textInput DOM element.
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    // use the DOM API to explicitly focus text-type input elements.
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

              <FloatingLabel 
              labelStyle={styles.labelInput}
              inputStyle={styles.input}
              style={styles.formInput}
              returnKeyType={"next"}
              onSubmitEditing={this.focusTextInput}>
                Email
            </FloatingLabel>
            <FloatingLabel
              ref={this.textInput} 
              labelStyle={styles.labelInput}
              inputStyle={styles.input}
              style={styles.formInput}
                Email 2
            </FloatingLabel>
```

**Example**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }



 render() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
        placeholder="testpalce"
        style={{width:"90%",height:20,borderColor:"black",borderWidth:1}}
        returnKeyType={"next"}
        onSubmitEditing={this.focusTextInput}
        />
        <TextInput 
        ref={this.textInput}
        placeholder="next"
        style={{width:"90%",height:20,borderColor:"black",borderWidth:1}}
        returnKeyType={"next"}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems:"center"

  }
});
```

Comment: What if I have multiple TextInput (around 50), then do I need to create multiple focusTextInput function.?

Comment: You can also refer to it directly. `ref={ text => this.textinput = text}`

Comment: @vickykeshri If my answer was helpful, could you check the arrow and 'V' signs?